# Flutter:Immediately received new config in client from remote when changed config from console

Tags: flutter, firebase-remote-config

I create a service to get config from Firebase remote config:

```
const String _ShowDataBanner = "show_data_banner";
const String _ShowMainBanner = "show_main_banner";
const String _ShowMainColorBanner = "show_main_color_banner";

class RemoteConfigService {
  final RemoteConfig _remoteConfig;
  final defaults = <String, dynamic>{
    _ShowMainBanner: false,
    _ShowMainColorBanner: "0xffcccccc"
  };

  RemoteConfigService({RemoteConfig remoteConfig})
      : _remoteConfig = remoteConfig;

  static RemoteConfigService _instance;
  static Future<RemoteConfigService> getInstance() async {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = RemoteConfigService(
        remoteConfig: await RemoteConfig.instance,
      );
    }
    return _instance;
  }

  String get showMainBanner => _remoteConfig.getString(_ShowDataBanner);

  Future initialise() async {
    try {
      await _remoteConfig.setDefaults(defaults);
      await _fetchAndActivate();
    } on FetchThrottledException catch (e) {
      print("Remote config fetch throttled: $e");
    } catch (e) {
      print(
          "unable to fetch remote config. Catched or default values will be used");
    }
  }

  Future _fetchAndActivate() async {
    // await _remoteConfig.fetch();
    await _remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: Duration(seconds: 0));
    _remoteConfig
        .activateFetched()
        .then((value) => print("---------> ${value.toString()}"));
  }
}
```

When i change config from Firebase console I have to stop/start app to updated my config.It is possible to received new config in client from remote immediately when i changed config from console?

Comment: [This documentation page](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes) might show what is needed in order to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase remote config is not meant to be used like this. Its not a real-time thing. But if you want to update immediately after updating config from firebase console, then you can do that by providing expiration parameter a duration of 0 seconds.

```dart
await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: const Duration(seconds: 0));
```

It will fetch the latest values every time but this is not recommended as you can also get FetchThrottledException.

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<RemoteConfig> setupRemoteConfig() async {
  final RemoteConfig remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.instance;
  await remoteConfig.ensureInitialized();
  await remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();
  var hello = remoteConfig.getString("hello");
  print("hello: |${hello}|");

  return remoteConfig;
}
```

`await remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();` is very important.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to fetch and activate current data:

```
FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance.fetchAndActivate().whenComplete(() => FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance.getBool(remoteKey));
```